# Value of e.target.value undefinned

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a let: valorImput, coming from an  e.target.value from input.
I use this value to compare it with a value in an array and it works. But when I want to get its value it said undefined and I'm not able to use it in future functions.
This is a link to [Codesand](https://codesandbox.io/s/diego-q6p60b?file=/index.js:2662-2701) with the whole code.

```
let valorImput = ""; 
dropDown.onchange = (e) => {
          valorImput = e.target.value;
          console.log("dropdown onchange console", e.target.value);
};
    
btn.onclick = (e) => {
      const existe = productos.find((x) => x.titulo === valorImput);
      existe ? (precio = existe.precio) : console.log("NO hay Nada");
      document.getElementById("valorDeSelect").value = precio;
       Swal.fire("El precio esta expresado en Dolares!", "USD " + precio, "success");
console.log("valor input", valorImput);
};
```

Comment: Please include in your post declaration of `valorImput` also everywhere are using the variable

Comment: Hello Thanh, i did it now. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable `valorImput` must be declared in global scope (outside of any "{}" brackets).

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4sxzyatv/)

See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) for more detail.